# IOS Development, Unable to convert my NSData to NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:

Tags: ios, nsjsonserialization

Here is the below code I edited. Please help me out. I was trying to display the data in list view.

```
     NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];


     NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
     NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                 cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad
                                             timeoutInterval:30];

     if ([response statusCode] >= 200 && [response statusCode] < 300)
     {
         NSString *responseData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData
                                                                  options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
          NSLog(@"responseData : %@", responseData);
         NSArray *entries = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[responseData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                            options:0 error:&error];


When I keep a log for NSURL it is navigating to the web service and gives me a result that I need, but the problem arises at responseData
```

Comment: So, what does `error` tell you?

Comment: Yes, the error would be useful too. Also, what IS happening? You didn't say what was going wrong.

Comment: And your code appears to be badly mucked up.  Is `responseData` really an NSString???

Comment: @HotLicks he's taking the string and converting it back to data.

Comment: Wait... what? You're... ok, just look at my answer. It will fix it.

Comment: @Fogmeister - It's unclear what he's doing.

Comment: @HotLicks yeah, I'd assumed the top line was `stringFromData`.

Comment: When I use 
 NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
         NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                     cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad
                                                 timeoutInterval:30];
         
         NSLog(@"urlData1 : %@", urlData);
         NSLog(@"urlRequest : %@", urlRequest);
The Log I got is correct..

Comment: We have no idea what data you're getting where.  For starters, convert `urlData` to NSString and log that -- show us the results (edit into your question).  Then we will have a starting point.

Comment: Can you post the actual data that came from urlData?  From your code it looks like you're double encoding your JSON on the server, something like:  `"[{\"ID_PROJECT:\"...`

Answer (score -1):

You are converting your data into a string and then back into data.

Just use the data that you get in the first place...

```
urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                returningResponse:&response
                                            error:&error];

if ([response statusCode] >= 200
    && [response statusCode] < 300)
{
    NSArray *entries = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData
                                                       options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                                                         error:&error];

    // do something with the JSON object
}
```

This should be all you need to do.

**EDIT**

OK, do this and report back what it says...

```
urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                returningResponse:&response
                                            error:&error];

if ([response statusCode] >= 200
    && [response statusCode] < 300)
{
    NSString *theJSONString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"The JSON is... %@", theJSONString);
}
```

This will at least give us an idea of what exactly is coming through.

Comment: When I use the above code, Result is 2014-11-03 12:02:23.983 TimesheetIOS[24108:4038141] responseData : (null)
2014-11-03 12:02:23.984 TimesheetIOS[24108:4038141] Error : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x7d1253c0 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

Comment: @user3440782 please just show the JSON that you get from the api. Don't try to convert it to anything. Just print the JSON.

Comment: @user3440782 I've edited the answer slightly. Try the new code. If that doesn't work please try the debugging stuff I put at the end so we can try to diagnose what is going on.

Comment: Here we go 

[{\"ID_PROJECT\":0,\"NM_PROJECT\":\"INVALID\",\"ID_TASK\":0,\"TASk_NAME\":\"INVALID\",\"ID_SUB_TASK\":0,\"SUBTASK_NAME\":\"INVALID\",\"No_Hours\":0,\"dt_event\":\"INVALID\",\"supervisor\":\"INVALID\",\"ID_TIMESHEET_DTLS\":0,\"STATUS\":null,\"FL_APPROVE\":\"0\",\"NM_LEAVE\":null}]

Comment: @user3440782 did you try the (slightly updated) code in the first code snippet? Does it still show the same error? Also, is that **exactly** what was logged out?

Comment: Yes is the above result I Posted just now

Comment: [{\"ID_PROJECT\":0,\"NM_PROJECT\":\"INVALID\",\"ID_TASK\":0,\"TASk_NAME\":\"INVA‌​LID\",\"ID_SUB_TASK\":0,\"SUBTASK_NAME\":\"INVALID\",\"No_Hours\":0,\"dt_event\":‌​\"INVALID\",\"supervisor\":\"INVALID\",\"ID_TIMESHEET_DTLS\":0,\"STATUS\":null,\"‌​FL_APPROVE\":\"0\",\"NM_LEAVE\":null}]

Comment: @user3440782 yes please. It's not really clear what you are doing or what is going wrong.

Comment: Why are you converting the data into a string? It makes no sense?

Comment: Do we have any option without converting the data to a string and displaying in List view?

Comment: Here is the result when we keep a log for NSData if it is helpful for you. 
<225b7b5c 2249445f 50524f4a 4543545c 223a302c 5c224e4d 5f50524f 4a454354 5c223a5c 22494e56 414c4944 5c222c5c 2249445f 5441534b 5c223a30 2c5c2254 41536b5f 4e414d45 5c223a5c >

Comment: @user3440782 you are not trying to create a string. You are trying to create an NSArray. **Did you try my updated code?** you still haven't answered it? I added the option for the NSJSON function.